# Keyevents in Pseudoterminals

Tags: go, websocket, keyevent, pty

I have a program to create pseudo terminals which uses https://github.com/creack/pty for Unix and [https://github.com/ActiveState/termtest/conpty](https://github.com/ActiveState/termtest/tree/master/conpty) for windows.

I have a terminal emulator which uses a WebSocket to read & write commands to the pseudoterminal.

I have configured it to run from the home directory of the root user (`/var/root` or `C:\Windows\system32`) as well as the current user (`/Users/userName` or `C:\Users\userName`) based on my selection.

But, in both Unix & Windows, I couldn't able to perform key events like ctrl+r (UNIX for search) & tab (for autocompletion), and so on.

Please drop some resources or ways that could be helpful in acheiving keyevents in pseudoterminal.

Comment: As pointed out in the answer below, you'll need a terminal emulator: ActiveState/termtest comes with a terminal emulator ActiveState/vt10x, so you can see how it is done there.  This is function that creates key events: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ActiveState/termtest#ConsoleProcess.Send

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-terminal doesn't have an established provision to handle key events.

It should be captured & sent along with commands.

https://github.com/fyne-io/terminal is a terminal emulator which handles key events.